# Retrieving an element from a created list

Tags: c#, sql, list

I created an list named 'PTNList', and everything I needed added to it just fine.  Now I am attempting to write code to retrieve each element from that list and run it against an SQL query.  I have a feeling  I'm not sure exactly how to about this.  The CompareNumbers.txt file generates, but nothing is printed to it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the section of code I believe needs to be worked with.

```
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:/temp/CompareNumbers.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))


            foreach (var ptn in PTNList)
            {
                //create sql for getting the count using "ptn" as the variable thats changing
                //call DB with sql
                //Get count from query, write it out to a file;

                Console.WriteLine("Running Query");
                string query2 = @"SELECT COUNT(PRODUCT_TYPE_NO)
                                    AS NumberOfProducts
                                    FROM dbo.PRODUCT
                                    Where PRODUCT_TYPE_NO = " + ptn;



                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2);
                cmd2.Connection = con;

                rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(rdr["NumberOfProducts"]);
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
```

Comment: When the query runs, is rdr.HasRows true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't used apostrophes around the values. But you should use parameters anyway. You could use one query instead of one for every type. For example with this  approach:

```
string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(PRODUCT_TYPE_NO) AS NumberOfProducts
               FROM dbo.PRODUCT
               Where PRODUCT_TYPE_NO IN ({0});";

string[] paramNames = PTNList.Select(
    (s, i) => "@type" + i.ToString()
).ToArray();

string inClause = string.Join(",", paramNames);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format(sql, inClause)))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], PTNList[i]);
    }

    // con.Open(); // if not already open
    int numberOfProducts = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

**Update**: maybe you really just want to loop them and get their count. Then you don't need this complex approach. But you should still use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection and other issues like missing apostrophes etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to output a text file with the count numbers.  It should be a simple thing, but I tend to make everything difficult on myself...

Comment: @enigmahfc: use `Where PRODUCT_TYPE_NO = @type` instead of `Where PRODUCT_TYPE_NO = " + ptn;`. Then use the (single) sql-parameter as shown above.

Comment: That seems to have worked.  Thank you for that, I was bashing my head over here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to convert the column back to a type, e.g.

```
sw.WriteLine(rdr["NumberOfProducts"] as string);
```

Also, note that your query is prone to SqlInjection attacks and should be parameterized, and that `SqlCommand` is also disposable. You can squeeze a bit more performance by reusing the `SqlCommand`:

```
string query2 = @"SELECT COUNT(PRODUCT_TYPE_NO)
                    AS NumberOfProducts
                    FROM dbo.PRODUCT
                    Where PRODUCT_TYPE_NO = @ptn";

using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2))
{
    cmd2.Connection = con;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ptn", SqlDbType.Varchar);
    foreach (var ptn in PTNList)
    {
        cmd2.Parameters["@ptn"].Value = ptn;

        Console.WriteLine("Running Query");
        using var (rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
          if (rdr.Read())
          {
              sw.WriteLine(rdr["NumberOfProducts"] as string);
          }
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your query give an result and sw.WriteLine is executed? I would redesign your code like this, becfause if you have an error in your data query, you might get into trouble. I always like to use this (schema):

```
IDataReader reader = null;

try
{
// create every thing...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
// catch all exceptions
}
finally()
{
    if(reader != null)
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

And use the same for your connection, so that you can be sure, it is closed correct.